# How to prevent axis from auto-scaling?

Tags: c#, oxyplot

Each time I add new data to series, Y axis is panning/zooming automatically in order to fit new data into screen. How can I prevent Oxyplot from touching the axis? I would like to have the scale fixed all the time, no matter what data I feed to plot

Comment: I do not know oxyplot; in a ms chart you would set the axis range i.e. axis.minimum & maximum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Taw stated, the properties in oxyplot are the same:

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Left,
    Minimum = 0,
    Maximum = 10,
});

plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
    Minimum = 0,
    Maximum = 10,
});
```